# $watch do not handling mutations in VueJS Component prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js v1.0.24. In component `Vue.component` I have a prop `events` and handling this using:

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '<div id="my-component"></div>',

  props: {
    events: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },

    event: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },

  ready: function() {
    // ...

    this.$watch('events', function (value, mutation) {
      if (mutation) {
        console.log(
          mutation.method,
          mutation.args,
          mutation.result,
          mutation.inserted,
          mutation.removed)
      }
    })
  },

  //...
}
```

Whenever I push something in events, the `$watch` triggers, but the result is:

`undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined`

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: watch receives (newValue, oldValue) parameters. I can't check right now but i think that when you're watching array you'll receive whole array in those.

Comment: The problem is `newValue === oldValue` for mutate objects, maybe $watch isn't the solution I need. You're right, my params seem to be wrong.

Comment: Yea, there is no mutation parameter for `$watch`.  You'd need to parse through the arrays and figure out what was added or deleted yourself.  Also, check out Vuex if you need a more complex state management system than vanilla Vue has https://github.com/vuejs/vuex